# Spinner from database - get value

Tags: java, android

I am learning Android and I use this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/06/android-populating-spinner-data-from-sqlite-database/ to generate Spinner with data from database.
This working ok, but i can't get selected item.

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); //this is ok
```

and next i would like get selected item:

```
Log.i("test", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

this return me:

> +++ LOG: entry corrupt or truncated

**EDIT:**

I try also:

```
Log.i("test", spinner.getSelectedView().toString());
```

but this return:

```
android.widget.TextView@410a2ae8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)spinner.getSelectedView();
String result = textView.getText().toString();
```